# to change the date based on exif data since export from Mac Photos shows date of export using exiftool

Tags: mac, high-sierra, photos

I used the following to change the Date Created to the actual date the photo was taken because exporting from Photos showed the date of export.
"for file in *; do SetFile -d "$(exiftool -p '$CreateDate' -d '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' "$file")" "$file"; done"

I got the following warning:
"Warning: [minor] Adjusted MakerNotes base by 46 - IMG_1369.JPG" -- what does this mean?

I found the above suggestion at this thread:
[Export from Mac Photos app while keeping date created data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256837/export-from-mac-photos-app-while-keeping-date-created-data?newreg=b71dff9e60a342b59c2eaea980b748be)

Also what is the cmd to change "Date Modifed" using exiftool?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message seems to be related to that one picture. Other files did not return any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a test, I exported six photos as **JPG** *files* from **Photos**, on **macOS High Sierra**, into a new *folder*.

Then in **Terminal** I *change directory* to the new *folder* containing the exported photos and ran the following *command* to change both the **create** and **modify** *date/time* from the **EXIF** info:

```bash
for f in *; do SetFile -d "$(exiftool -p '$CreateDate' -d '%m/%d/%Y %T' "${f}")" -m "$(exiftool -p '$ModifyDate' -d '%m/%d/%Y %T' "${f}")" "${f}"; done
```

The prompt returned without error, and the exported *files* now have the original **create** and **modify** *date/time*.

Comment: Is there a similar command that would work for video files (.MOV)?

Comment: @imac2, Because of `for f in *;` the same command works on any files that returns the _value_ of `'$CreateDate'` and `'$ModifyDate'` from `exiftool`. If you want to limit it to a particular _file type_, then use, e.g.:  `for f in *.MOV; ...`

Comment: I got the following warnings when I tested it on two .MOV files. "Warning: [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the media data - IMG_7264.MOV
Warning: [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the media data - IMG_7264.MOV
I got the same two warnings each for both the files.
 -- Although it did still change the dates but the time stamp seems to be off. I think it is something to do with UTC time stamp. Are these error warnings relevant or can it be ignored? Any suggestion on how to correct the time stamp offset? Thanks.