# How to keep photo date when dragging photos out of Photos app into a folder on Mac?

Tags: mac, icloud, finder, photos, metadata

I have encountered what is to me a deeply distressing and frustrating behavior of the Photos app for Mac. I would like to know if there is a workaround.

**A bit of background:** I use iCloud to sync my photos between devices. Therefore, the photos I take on my iPhone automatically appear in the Photos app on my Mac. Note that Photos kindly sorts my photos by capture date with old photos toward the top and new photos toward the bottom. That convention helps me find photos more easily. However, I want to use the Photos *exclusively for personal memories*—not the photos I take for work.

**What I've tried:** I opened a destination folder for my work photos and dragged the work photos from the Photos app into it. The creation/modification date is automatically set to the *current time*. I understand how this makes sense to a computer diligently recording that new file was created today, but it's very unhelpful for humans because it is apparently impossible to retain the photos' capture dates. I want to sort my work photos by their capture date (original creation date) in Finder. I don't care at all about the date I happened to drag them out of the Photos app.

Besides drag+drop, I have also tried *exporting* the photos using various settings. All attempts have been unsuccessful. Is there a workaround?

**Update:** My question is evidently similar to another question. As I understand it (though some answers are pretty technical), I am asked to select the work photos in Photos app and then choose from the menu bar File > Export > Export Unmodified Original… I have tried this.

I'll run through it again and share what I see step-by-step. I am given the option to "Export IPTC as XMP". I don't know what that means, but in this run-through, I'll leave it unchecked. I will also choose "Use File Name" for the "File Name" field. I will leave the "Subfolder Format" set to "None". I then click "Export" and choose the destination folder. The Creation Date and Modified Date in Finder is 4:09pm today (current time).

Varying attempts have yielded this:

[image]

I just selected many photos (from a week ago) and attempted to export in one go. The results yielded a surprise. Inexplicably, 4 photos claim to be from July 19, a few days after they were actually taken. Not sure why those didn't get set to current date/time?

[image]

Comment: Your question is similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256837/88313).  Have you tried the answers provided there, specifically about exporting unmodified images (you mentioned you tried exporting but didn't indicate how you did it)?

Comment: Looks like I found the same question as @fsb did. If those answers don't work for you, please [edit] to explain what happens.

Comment: I've tried the proposed solutions and I think my problem is different somehow. Nothing is working. Please consider reopening the question because I would like to solve this today.

Comment: The solutions in the original question will work for what you're trying to do.  For example, I used exiftool to rename a few dozen photos and add the date taken (from the exif info) to the file name, then I sorted by that.  You can also use A Better Finder Rename to do this with a UI.